# ERROR : "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that > corresponds to your MySQL server "

Tags: php, syntax-error

I got an error while using function below , I'm writing Plug-in for WordPress :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near **'0,'1'**,'', )' at line 2

Input values were :
'user1', 'pass1', 'fredy','lincoln','Batman',0,'0987','31231',1980

result query is :

```
 query("INSERT INTO tblusers(UserUserName,UserPassword,UserFirstName,UserLastName,UserNickName,UserSex,UserMobile,UserNationalCode,UserBirthDate)
 VALUES ( 'user1', 'pass1', 'fredy','lincoln',,0,'1','', ) ") //error is here//
```

.

```
function complete_registration() {
    global  $wpdb,$reg_errors, $username, $password, $email, $mobile, $first_name, $last_name, $nickname,$gender, $birthdate ;
    if ( 1 > count( $reg_errors->get_error_messages() ) ) {
$wpdb->show_errors();
        $wpdb = new wpdb('username','*****','mydb','x.x.x.x');
    $wpdb->tblusers =  'tblusers';
        $sql = $wpdb->prepare( "INSERT INTO $wpdb->tblusers(UserUserName,UserPassword,UserFirstName,UserLastName,UserNickName,UserSex,UserMobile,UserNationalCode,UserBirthDate)
        VALUES ( %s, %s, %s,%s,$s,%d,%s,%s,$s )
" ,
            array(
                $username,
                $password,
                $first_name,
                $last_name,
                $nickname,
                $gender,
                $mobile,
                $email,
                $birthdate
            ) );
            $wpdb->query($sql);

}
```

Comment: `'lincoln',,0` probably because you have two ,,?

Comment: yes, but according to my input :  'user1', 'pass1', 'fredy','lincoln','Batman',0,'0987','31231',1980 , there was 'Batman' . I don't know why it turned to ,, !!!

Comment: well most probably your $nickname variable is empty

Comment: Batman disappeared! On a more serious note, you have `$s` instead of `%s` where Batman was in `VALUES`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a couple of typos, `$s` instead of `%s`, that cause Batman and 1980 to disappear:

```
VALUES ( %s, %s, %s,%s,$s,%d,%s,%s,$s )
```

Just change it to:

```
VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %d, %s, %s, %s)
```

Answer (score 0):

try something close to this

```
query("INSERT INTO tblusers(UserUserName,UserPassword,UserFirstName,UserLastName,UserNickName,UserSex,UserMobile,UserNationalCode,UserBirthDate)
 VALUES ( 'user1', 'pass1', 'fredy','lincoln','nickname','male','+254716370730','254','1993-02-18' ) ")
```

cheers